How to locate the most sparse point within a defined 2D region?
The core of the problem is to algorithmically determine the coordinates of the point E that maximizes the distance to the nearest other point in the bounded 2D space.
For example, in the space defined by the coordinates [(0, 0), (1, 1)], which contains the points A₁, B₁, C₁, and D₁ shown below, the target "most sparse" point is E₁ (0.5, 0.5):

In other words, by the target point E, I mean the coordinates of this "most sparse" point (the point with the minimum density), rather than selecting it from the existing set of points.
So, can you suggest an efficient algorithm or approach to solve this problem?

You could make the Voronoi diagram with one of the algorithms listed on the same Wikipedia page.
Then consider all of the following vertices:

The four corners of the bounding rectangle
The intersection points of the Voronoi diagram and the bounding rectangle
The vertices of the Voronoi diagram that are inside the bounding rectangle

Check which of these points is the "most sparse".

IIUC, basically you want to push away the center of the space to the farthest extremity from the nearest point(s). If so, with python, you could invert a minimize objective of the min/distance between the space's centroid (which is used as an initial guess) and the set of points :
def repulse(points, space):
    minx, miny, maxx, maxy = space.bounds
    return minimize(
        lambda p: -min(Point(p).distance(Point(coo)) for coo in points),
        *space.centroid.coords,
        bounds=[(minx, maxx), (miny, maxy)],
    ).x  # solution of the OptimizeResult

print(repulse((A1, B1, C1, D1), space1)) # [0.5 0.5]
print(repulse((A2, B2), space2))         # [2.4 1. ]


Setup :
from scipy.optimize import minimize
from shapely import Point, box

space1 = box(0, 0, 1, 1)
A1 = (0.9, 0.9)
B1 = (0.9, 0.1)
C1 = (0.1, 0.1)
D1 = (0.1, 0.9)

space2 = box(1.4, 0, 2.4, 1)
A2 = (1.6, 0.2)
B2 = (1.5, 0.1)

